# How to reject duplicate PHP socket connection from the same client?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

**I want to reject duplicate socket connection when the same connected client try to connect again.**
The below code I tried to store gamerId into an array then later check the array if new gamerId already exist or not. But seems the duplicate connection already made but I don't want to make any duplicate connection.

```
$address = '127.0.0.5';
$port = 8085;

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die('Not Created');
$bind = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die("Not Binded");

$listen = socket_listen($sock, 1) or die("Didnot listen");

$accept = socket_accept($sock) or die("Not Accepted");
$readData = trim(socket_read($accept, 1024));

$gamerId = array();
$errHandler = array();
$gamerIdlen = count($gamerId);


function checkDuplicate($gamerId, $gamerIdLen, $readData, $errHandler)
{

    for ($i = 0; $i < $gamerIdLen; $i++) {

        if ($gamerId[$i] === $readData) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

if (checkDuplicate($gamerId, $gamerIdlen, $readData, $errHandler) == 1) {
    array_push($errHandler,  "exist");
} else if (checkDuplicate($gamerId, $gamerIdlen, $readData, $errHandler) != 1) {
    array_push($gamerId, $readData);
}


do {

 global $accept;
 $accept = socket_accept($sock) or die("Not Accepted");

    print_r($errHandler);
    print_r($gamerId);


} while (true);
```

Comment: Your server seems to handle one connection at a time, try using socket_select https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php

Comment: @IbrahimSharaf because I gave 1 to to backlog parameter? `$listen = socket_listen($sock, 1) or die("Didnot listen");`

Answer (score 0):

Keep a map of sockets to identities and close a (new) socket after identifying, when an identity is already in the map.

```
$map = [
  [socket1] => User(123),
  [socket1] => User(124),
];
```

Comment: you mean if my client name is client-1 I will predefined an array with that client (client-1) name? like `$gamerId = array("client-1", "client-2");

Comment: I suppose after accepting a new socket you receive some sort of credentials or login token to identify a real person. After identifying just store a reference between the socket and the user (gamerId?). But first make sure there is no active session for this user in yout map. Also be sure to remove the session, when a socket leaves/disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

$address = '127.0.0.5';
$port = 8085;

$server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die('Not Created');
socket_bind($server, $address, $port) or die("Not Binded");

socket_listen($server, 10) or die("Did not listen");

// clients before checking gamerId
$pending = [];
// accepted clients
$clients = [];
// gamerId list
$gamerIds = [];

// gamerId for socket
$clientsIds = new WeakMap();

echo "Listening...\n";

do {
    // wait for new client and new data on sockets
    $read = [$server, ...$pending, ...$clients];
    $write = null;
    $error = null;
    if(socket_select($read, $write, $error)){
        foreach($read as $socket){
            if($socket === $server){
                // new connection
                $pending[] = socket_accept($server);
                printf("New Socket connected\n");
            } else if(in_array($socket, $pending, true)) {
                // data for pending connection
                $readData = socket_read($accept, 1024);

                // remove key from pending
                if (($key = array_search($socket, $pending, true)) !== false) {
                    array_splice($pending, $key, 1);
                }

                // client disconnected already
                if($readData === false){
                    printf("Pending client disconnected #%d\n", (int)$socket);
                    socket_close($socket);
                    unset($socket);
                    continue;
                }

                // here should be something to extract gamerId (e.g. make sure it is X characters)
                $readData = trim($readData);

                if(in_array($readData, $gamerIds, true)){
                    printf("Pending client already connected #%d, blocked...\n", (int)$socket);
                    // close connection
                    socket_close($socket);
                    unset($socket);
                } else {
                    printf("Pending client accepted #%d\n", (int)$socket);
                    // accept client
                    $clients[] = $socket;
                    $gamerIds[] = $readData;
                    $clientsIds[$socket] = $readData;
                }
            } else {
                // client communication
                $readData = socket_read($accept, 1024);

                if($readData === false){
                    printf("Client disconnected #%d\n", (int)$socket);
                    // remove client
                    if (($key = array_search($socket, $clients, true)) !== false) {
                        array_splice($clients, $key, 1);
                    }

                    // remove gamerId from the list
                    if(isset($clientsIds[$socket])){
                        if (($key = array_search($clientsIds[$socket], $gamerIds, true)) !== false) {
                            array_splice($gamerIds, $key, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    socket_close($socket);
                    unset($socket);
                } else {
                    // handle data...
                    printf("Data received from socket #%d\n", (int)$socket);
                }

            }
        }
    }
} while (true);
```

Comment: Why do i need socket_select($read, $write, $error)?

Comment: To handle multiple sockets at the same time like server/clients, especially when you want to filter some connections. Without that one client can DOS your server by opening connection and not sending any data.